# React useState with sorted array does not cause re-render of SemanticUI table if initial sorting is done

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a table with SemanticUI that renders a list of companies and allows the list to be resorted based on clicking the header of the table.  I thought I had this wrapped up working fine (the dev env is sending me a pre-sorted list), but when writing tests, I realized I cannot guarantee the list is pre-sorted.
So I edited my initial `useState` logic to have a sort function which is the same logic for the header click:

BEFORE (works):
`const [data, setData] = useState(companies);`

AFTER (does not work):
`const [data, setData] = useState(companySortData(companies, COLUMN_NAME.NAME));`

The initial UI looks OK with both above, but when I click the header, this is where the issue appears: the UI does not change (re-render).

In my stepping through the code, I see that the correctly RE-sorted array is there, but somewhere in the React internals, the array does not trigger a state change.

I have tried a plethora of options including: 1) changing the state so that the `data` is part of the `sortedColumnData`, 2) making an `useEffect` hook that allows for the initial company data to be there and then we `setData`.  3) trying to create a `usePrevious` hook that compares the `sortedColumnData` and then calls `setData` if that dependency changes.  4) changed from a Functional to PureComponent, but this isn't fully solving it either.

I know that React only shallow diffs so that might be part of it, but the data array shape itself is shallow so I thought this would be picked up (which is does if I do not initial sort data):

```
{
  id: "newnew",
  name: "A New New Company",
  subdomain: "newnew",
  createdAt: "2019-10-28T21:54:30.253Z",
  updatedAt: "2019-10-28T21:54:30.253Z"
},
```

So, here is a CodeSandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-thompson-vg2x1

Here is the component itself:

```
export const CompanyTable = ({ companies }) => {
  const [sortedColumnData, setSortedColumnData] = useState({
    data: companySortData(companies, COLUMN_NAME.NAME), // swap this initial sorting with just the `companies` and this table works fine
    direction: DIRECTION.ASCENDING,
    columnName: COLUMN_NAME.NAME
  });

  const handleClick = clickedColumn => {
    if (!clickedColumn) return;

    if (sortedColumnData.columnName !== clickedColumn) {
      setSortedColumnData({
        data: companySortData(sortedColumnData.data, clickedColumn),
        columnName: clickedColumn,
        direction: DIRECTION.ASCENDING
      });
      return;
    }

    setSortedColumnData({
      data: sortedColumnData.data.reverse(),
      columnName: clickedColumn,
      direction:
        sortedColumnData.direction === DIRECTION.ASCENDING
          ? DIRECTION.DESCENDING
          : DIRECTION.ASCENDING
    });
  };
  return (
    <Table celled selectable sortable>
      <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
          {headerCells.map(cell => (
            <Table.HeaderCell
              key={`cell-${cell.testid}`}
              sorted={
                sortedColumnData.columnName === cell.clickHandlerText
                  ? sortedColumnData.direction
                  : undefined
              }
              data-testid={`header-${cell.testid}`}
              onClick={() => handleClick(cell.clickHandlerText)}
            >
              {cell.title}
            </Table.HeaderCell>
          ))}
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Header>
      <Table.Body data-testid="company-table-body">
        {sortedColumnData.data.map(
          ({ id, name, subdomain, createdAt, updatedAt }) => {
            return (
              <Table.Row
                key={id}
                role="link"
                data-testid={id}
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              >
                <Table.Cell singleLine>{name}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell singleLine>{subdomain}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell singleLine>{createdAt}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell singleLine>{updatedAt}</Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            );
          }
        )}
      </Table.Body>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

I am not sure why the re-rendering from setting state with the re-sorted array is failing...

Comment: I checked your sandbox link, seems to be working fine. Can you help me understand better?

Comment: @VaibhavSingh, sorry, I had re-saved the sandbox with the plain `companies` in the initial state setting.  I moved it back so the sorting happens on initial state set. click the header row to toggle ascending/descending order change.

Comment: Check my answer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its happening because you passed the reference of your props to sort function and trying to set it in state, you cannot mutate a prop, its the fundamental of React. If you want to store a prop into state kill the reference first. Hope it answers your doubt :)

```
  const companySortData = (data, sortBy) => {
  let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  return copyData.sort((a, b) => {
    let x = a[sortBy];
    let y = b[sortBy];
    if (sortBy === COLUMN_NAME.CREATED || sortBy === COLUMN_NAME.UPDATED) {
      x = new Date(a.createdAt);
      y = new Date(b.createdAt);
    } else {
      x = a[sortBy].toLowerCase();
      y = b[sortBy].toLowerCase();
    }
    return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
  });
};
```

Comment: i will mark this as answer.  But with a slight update, instead of stringify, replace with array spread like: `  const copy = [...data];`

Comment: @PhilLucks That will work, but spread operator creates a shallow copy while stringify will create a deep copy.