# How to pass a state to another state in same component using functional component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In that project I am trying to sorting. In my component I have

Two buttons. The first button is Change to Min and the second button is Change to Max.

And in the same component I am showing the data that is coming from the backend.

Now If I click the button the sorting logic state has to apply to the data what I am showing by

Using the map method.

This is list.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import Aumservice from '../../service/aum-service';
import { MdEdit } from 'react-icons/md';
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";


const List = (props) => {

const [sortData, setSortData] = useState(null)

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
        (async function () {
            const response = await Aumservice.getAum()
            const dataResponse = response.data.list.map(ele => ele.maxValue)
            setSortData(dataResponse)
            setData(response.data.list)
        })()
    }, [])

const sortAscending = () => {
        let sortedData = sortData.sort((a, b) => a - b)
        console.log(sortedData)
        setData(sortedData)
    }
    const sortDescending = () => {
        let sortedData = sortData.sort((a, b) => b - a)
        setData(sortedData)
    }

return (
        <div>
<IconContext.Provider
                value={{ size: '25px' }}
            >
                <Table bordered>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>So No</th>
                            <th>Min</th>
                            <th>Max</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {setData.map((currentValue, index) => {
                            return < tr key={index + 1} >
                                <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                                <td>{currentValue.minValue}</td>
                                <td>{currentValue.maxValue}</td>
                               </tr>
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </IconContext.Provider>
            <div className='min pr-5'>
                <Button onClick={sortAscending} className='primary'>Change to Min</Button>
            </div>
            <div className='max'>
                <Button className='secondary'>Change to Max</Button>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default List
```

If I am not clear with my doubt please put a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you want your data to be sorted by `maxValue`, in a way that depends on which button is clicked (ascending/descending).

1. There is a typo in the mapping element, instead of `setData.map((..` you need `data.map((..`.
2. An `onClick` event must be added at the second button with the `sortDescending` function.
3. You do not need a second variable `sortData` for sorting your data, you can sort the existing list that you get from the response.

According to the above conclusions, I have edited your code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import Aumservice from '../../service/aum-service';
import { MdEdit } from 'react-icons/md';
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";


const List = (props) => {


    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        (async function () {
            const response = await Aumservice.getAum()
            setData(response.data.list)
        })()
    }, [])

    const sortAscending = () => {
      let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      // If you want to sort by minValue,just change accordingly the below properties
      let sortedData = copyData.sort((a, b) => (a.maxValue > b.maxValue) ? 1 : -1);
      console.log(sortedData)
      setData(sortedData)
    }
    
    const sortDescending = () => {
      let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      // If you want to sort by minValue,just change accordingly the below properties
      let sortedData = copyData.sort((a, b) => (a.maxValue < b.maxValue) ? 1 : -1);
      console.log(sortedData)
      setData(sortedData)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <IconContext.Provider
                value={{ size: '25px' }}
            >
                <Table bordered>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>So No</th>
                        <th>Min</th>
                        <th>Max</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {data.map((currentValue, index) => {
                        return <tr key={index + 1} >
                                    <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                                    <td>{currentValue.minValue}</td>
                                    <td>{currentValue.maxValue}</td>
                                </tr>
                    })}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </IconContext.Provider>
            <div className='min pr-5'>
                <Button onClick={sortAscending} className='primary'>Change to Min</Button>
            </div>
            <div className='max'>
                <Button onClick={sortDescending} className='secondary'>Change to Max</Button>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default List
```

Comment: Hi @EvaBat  I tried your code its not working correctly.  It is working like this If I click  Change to min button then there is no change in the UI.

Comment: Hey @Vamsi, it would help if you could post your data structure in order to figure it out, I have used a list of objects with integers as maxValue property and it was working.

Comment: What I am trying to do is If I click the Change to Min button in UI Max value has to show numbers in Ascending order to Descending order. I have written your code and I have checked it in console it is showing numbers in Descending order. Again If I click the Change to Min button, Now the numbers are shown in Ascending order.  Mostly what I want is when I click Change to Min button what ever I am seeing in console it has to reflect to UI as well.

Comment: @Vamsi I have figured it out, I have updated my answer above according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272240/react-usestate-with-sorted-array-does-not-cause-re-render-of-semanticui-table-if)